# Returning list of items for a given template in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I am curious on how to replace wildcards with multiple elements from a list. For instance:

```
template = 'w**er'
some_list = ['a', 't']

# I want to create a loop that gives out the output: ['water', 'wtaer']
```

I tried playing around with my program and it is easy to replace the wildcard ('*') with only one character, however when there are multiple elements in a list, it complicates things and I am not sure how to do it.

#### Edit:

The loop I made:

```
for x in range(len(template)):
    if template[x] == '*':
        for y in range(len(letters)):
            template[x] = letters[y]
            word = ''.join(template)
            store.append(word)

store = ['wa*er', 'wt*er', 'wtaer', 'wtter']
```

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: Can elements repeat?

Comment: If you showed how you implemented it, someone might be able to help fix it.

Comment: @ScottHunter Added!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for `itertools.permutations`? You could replace * with a placeholder and use `str.format` to fill in:

```
from itertools import permutations
template = 'w{}{}er'
some_list = ['a', 't']
out = [template.format(*tpl) for tpl in permutations(some_list)]
```

Output:

```
['water', 'wtaer']
```